# "re.error: redefinition of group name" when using strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert this string into date format:

```
import datetime
my_string = "202206051234555555"
convert_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string, "%Y%M%d%H%M%S")
```

I am getting this error:

> re.error, redefinition of group name 'M' as group 5; was group 2

Can someone help in converting this string type to date? I want only date and I dont want time at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two main problems you had in your code were

1. You used `%M` (which stands for minutes) at the beginning instead of `%m` (which stands for months).
2. You tried to fit `555555` into `%s` (which takes only two digits i.e. doesn't take milliseconds), so I added `%f` to take care of that.

This should do the trick:

```
import datetime
my_string = "202206051234555555"
convert_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
```